# Disable scrolling with panel animation

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

In my navigation, the contact link slides down a panel which overlays on top of the site like so:

[image]

When the panel slides down I do not want the user to be able to scroll down below the panel. Basically, I want to disable scrolling on the page. If there is more content than available space within the panel, it will scroll within the panel. This is done simply by adding overflow:scroll to the panel's css like so:

```
#contactPanel{width:100%; height:100%; overflow:scroll;position: absolute; top:-100%; left:0; z-index: 6; background: #000000; color:white;}
```

So, scrolling is fine within the panel, but I do not want any scrolling within the body / document.

If not possible with pure CSS,javascript is an option.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I has another container with overflow:auto set, which was the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as your "contactPanel" is not larger than the body (or viewport) then the body won't scroll. But you can set overflow:hidden just to make sure of it. I'm guessing you actually only want to scroll the contactPanel vertically as well, and not on both axis? Use overflow-y:scroll;

I'd also recommend moving text styling rules onto to the text objects themselves... but that's just me.

```
body {
  overflow:hidden;
}

#contactPanel {
  overflow-y:scroll;

  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:-100%;
  left:0;
  z-index: 6;
  background: #000000;
}

#contactPanel p {
  color:#fff;
}
```